# multiply different type of numbers in php error

Tags: php

I imported an xml file to my website and i create a diferrent pricing based on the cost i buy the product. The problem is that gave me results floored and products with cost ex 0,43 turned to 0 . Price value is int and decimal. Msrp is zero most of the time in case it is not i use that for price.
Here is the code

```
<?php
 function choose_price_to_return($msrp, $price) {
     $price=number_format($price, 2, '.', '');
    if ($msrp > $price) {
        $actual_price=$msrp;
    } elseif (0<=$price and $price<1) {
          $actual_price=$price*4.00;
    } elseif (1<=$price and $price<2) {
          $actual_price=$price*3.00;
    } elseif (2<=$price and $price<3) {
          $actual_price=$price*2.00;
    } elseif (3<=$price and $price<4) {
          $actual_price=$price*1.90;
    } elseif (4<=$price and $price<5) {
          $actual_price=$price*1.80;
    } elseif (5<=$price and $price<6) {
          $actual_price=$price*1.70;
    } elseif (6<=$price and $price<7) {
          $actual_price=$price*1.60;
    } elseif (7<=$price and $price<8) {
          $actual_price=$price*1.50;
    } elseif (8<=$price and $price<9) {
          $actual_price=$price*1.49;
    } else {
          $actual_price=$price*1.40;
    }
    return $actual_price;
}
?>
```

Comment: If the value is actually `0,43`, then you would need to change the `,` to a `.` to be read properly.

Comment: You use `number_format()` inside a function, which results in a string. I think you mean to use [round($price,2)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php). Check the rounding methods there as well.

Comment: i changed `,` to `.` i have te same output . I will try round()